# How to set variables in an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am trying to read in a text file which has 21 names like this;

```
123, bill, bobs
124, joe, public
```

I have been able to put them into an array but I don't know how to set each name as a variable, as I need to sort them into alphabetical order based on their last name. This is my code so far;

```
$file = fopen("students.txt", "r");
If ($file) {
    while (!feof($file)) {
        $array = explode("/n", fread($file, filesize("students.txt")));
        print_r($array);
    }
} else {
    echo 'File unopened';
}
```

I have tried the following code but it doesnt seem to work;

```
fscanf ($fp, "%s, %s, %s/n", $num, $first, $last). "<br/>";
```

Comment: Have you even tried to make a sort using `usort()` or similar?

Comment: you've basically got CSV text. just use `fgetcsv()` to read each line into an array, then use `usort()` to define your own custom sort function for that array.

Comment: Btw, it's `\n` and not `/n`

Comment: @sohpie If any of the answers given below solve your problem you might upvote and accept one of them (the one that **you** find appropiate) to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the entire file into an array, and explode each line, then usort the results.

```
$array = file('your_file.txt');
if(false === $array) {
    // you had a problem reading file
    exit();
}

$exploded_array = array();
foreach($array as $csv) {
    $exploded_array[] = explode(',', $csv)
}

usort($exploded_array, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

You can also look at using `fgetscv()` instead of the combination of `file()` and `explode()`.  Either way it is pretty much the same.

Comment: Sorry about posting a similiar solution a few seconds later, but I had not received a notification about a new answer before posting mine.

Comment: @rangad No problem.  In looking at it, you actually covered one area I didn't, which is trimming the values.  If the file as as shown (with spaces after commas) this would be important.

Answer (score 0):

Your file related code is overcomplicated.

```
$users = file('students.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

array_walk($users, function (&$val) {
    $newAr = explode(',', $val);
    $val = array_map('trim', $newAr);
});

usort($users, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a[2], $b[2]);
});

var_dump($users);
```

[Example with fake data @3v4l](http://3v4l.org/WbRi2#v540)

Alternativly you may use `fgetcsv` to get the values from the file as @MarkB pointed out in the comments of your question